# grails CommandObject silent bind

Tags: grails

Is there a way to only bind the properties that exist on a command object?  The general concept is, i have a lot of different params in the map that I dont want to have to call out explicitly.

For instance, given the map

```
 def map = ['first': "Nick", 'last': "Capito", 'isRegistered': false ]


@grails.validation.Validateable
class EditCommand{
     String first
     String last 
}

def edit{ EditCommand command ->

}
```

Would crash, and throw an error `Message: No such property: isRegistered for class: EditCommand`

I have been doing it manually.

```
new EditCommand(params.findAll{['first', 'last'].grep(it.key)})
```

Comment: [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) to the rescue. In this case, the Command Object has to be explicitly bound to request instead of setting it as argument in action method and then exclude unwanted bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) as mentioned in my comment, in your particular case it will be something like

```
def edit = {->
    def cmd = new EditCommand()
    bindData(cmd, map, [exclude: ['isRegistered']])
    .......
}
```

In case, you do not want to exclude params, you can by default `include` all fields from the command object. By doing this you get the answer to your main question

*Is there a way to only bind the **properties that exist on a command object**?*
Yes, here is how it can be done..

```
def edit = {->
    def cmd = new EditCommand()
    //This has all the fields which is present in the Command Object
    //Others will be excluded by default
    def includedFields = 
            cmd.class.declaredFields.collectMany{!it.synthetic ? [it.name] : []}
    bindData(cmd, map, [include: includedFields])
    .......
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I dont want to do.. create a list of parameters to include OR exclude.

Comment: @Nix You have to at least include all the properties from the command object if you do not want to explicitly exclude anything. See my update above.

Comment: @Nix You wanted a fine grained approach to bind data, but you are not willing to use one.

Comment: No, I dont want a fine grained one, I want the opposite.

Comment: @Nix Was the update to answer helpful on achieving what you needed? Collecting all the fields in Command Object and binding them with the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the views to have a map/instance representing your command object rather than the top-level param map, you can achieve this cleanly:

view:

```
<g:textField name="editCommand.first" value="${editCommand.first}" />
```

controller:

```
def edit(@RequestParameter('editCommand') EditCommand editCommand) {
    if (params.boolean('isRegistered'))
        // etc.
}
```

or you can create the instance manually:

```
def edit() {
    EditCommand command = new EditCommand(params.editCommand)
    if (params.boolean('isRegistered'))
        // etc.
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to change the input parameter map, using `bindData` as dmahapatro suggested is the recommended way.

Comment: +1 for a form submission. What about a RESTful service with a query string? The url would end up like `http://mydomain/user?editCommand.first=John&editCommand.last=Doe&isRegistered=false`. Do we need to expose what we do in server side? Would appreciate your opinion. :-)

Comment: If you don't want scoped variables in your params, I'd make a command to represent that specific payload rather than just a portion of it. That is the original intent behind command objects in the first place.

Comment: Exactly my point. For an end client who consumes this REST Service should only bother about `first`, `last` and `age` as query params instead of asking them to scope each of them with our (producer's) command. Abstraction should be maintained. I would at least agree to have scoped variable if I am producing a service for B2B instead of B2C. Right?